# One main SSD, another for games?

Tags: ssd

My hard drive crashed. I'm looking at getting an SSD. The question I'm asking myself is do I get one large SSD (~180 GB) or two smaller ones (each ~90 GB)? I'd use one for my flight simulator (which is essentially self contained and does not rely on Windows OS files), the other for everything else (OS, files, work, music, etc.). I'm not interested in a RAID setup.

This would be for Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since they are SSDs, there is no performance benefit from splitting your files across multiple drives.

There is however the advantage of reducing loss should one of them die. That is of course up to your discretion based on the data you are storing on them and the price of getting one or two.

In my opinion you would better served putting all the replaceable files (OS, installed games and programs, etc.) on one drive and keeping all of your irreplaceable user-generated files on the other. Keeping them separate makes it safer and easier to backup.

Answer (score 0):

If you can fit the two ssd's, say two 120-128GBs, or the two 90GBs you mention, then a third very large HDD, 500GB to 2TB for backup, music, videos ect. That is best. If you just do one smaller ssd you'll eventually end up filling it up and needing more space, and buying one large ssd is a little more spendy. 
The best setup would be one ssd for OS, your most used programs and free space for future programs, the second ssd would be all games. And the third and only hdd is everything else that doesn't need speed. 
The ONLY reason to buy a larger ssd and not two smaller ones is if your mobo doesn't have enough sata connections. Being you can literally fit two ssd's of most sizes in a normal 3.5 slot with an adapter space shouldn't be an issue. There is ZERO performance loss from having two ssd's instead of one.